# How can I create a token that shows 6 decimals places in Eternl?

Tags: wallet, transaction, token, metadata

I have created my own token and I have added a Cardano Token Registry specifying that the token has 6 decimals places. My entry looks exactly like the Minswap's token entry, but the difference is that, when I want to send a transaction, I don't have the possibility to add decimal places, like I do have on the Minswap token.

Is there anything else I should do so my token shows like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if Eternl has this implemented, but there is a proposal that adds this token information to the metadata of the minting transaction:

https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/blob/1d9fbd0e29f07b931bf1524c7aed6635d478cd75/CIP-0035/CIP-0035.md

Minswap doesn't follow it, but Sundae does. Here's an example under Label 20:

https://cardanoscan.io/transaction/d74798c4a1e453fbc6ba4fbb1d785e0534fb8531fd1bc054ceff5b086240d3b5?tab=metadata

Probably worth a try.

Also, if your token is not correctly displayed in Eternl, you can click the "update" button (marked in red below), to re-fetch the data of your token from the Cardano Token Registry:

[image]

Comment: I tried also with that but it doesn't work. The problem is only in Eternl, in Nami and in Cardanoscan I can visualise the right amount of decimal places.

Comment: in discord it is suggested to "press the little update icon button to fetch the new registry data". Couldn't try it myself though

Answer (score 1):

Did you register your token at [CFtoken registry](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/cardano-token-registry) ? You can specify `decimals` as part of JSON you register on that repo.

Comment: Yes, I did, my entry looks exactly like the Minswap entry.

Comment: Any other suggestion? Because I still have this issue. The problem appears to be only with Eternl, in Nami it works fine.